# Report dependency version downloaded by Maven, given a version range

Tags: java, maven, versioning

Given a dependency declared as below in `pom.xml`

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>[1.0.0,5.0.0]</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Is there a Maven goal I can use to run to output the version picked by Maven out of the range?

EDIT: I understand the view against version ranges.  I'm not in the luxury of removing that from our project for the time being unfortunately.

Comment: [Baeldung has a great tutorial for this](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-dependency-latest-version), but I couldn't find any resource on Stack Overflow itself

Comment: @Lino, thanks.  That's interesting.  Didn't know about `Versions Maven Plugin`.  However, it's not clear to me how it can achieve what I need..

Comment: I strongly recommend **NOT** to use version ranges. Then you are sure that always exactly one version is picked and that your build is stable and reproducible. Finally the only correct answer would give you build... if check before the build during that time and the real build the version can change ... so from my point of view only the output during the build gives you the 100% accurate answer.

Comment: @khmarbaise, thanks.  I understand the view against version ranges.  I'm not in the luxury of removing that from our project for the time being unfortunately.

Comment: This means only accurate way is to look at the build output ... any other lookup beforehand is not accurate.